# I keep gettings the Error Unexpected token '?' when using NodeJS and Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I keep gettings the Error Unexpected token '?' when using NodeJS and Firebase Functions. I don't have any '?' token in my code, so think it's in the node_modules. I pasted my code below.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

// 99 Names of Allah
app.get('/99Names', (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('99namesofallah.json')));
});

// Duas
app.get('/duas', (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('dua/duas.json')));
});

app.get('/duas/:edition', (req, res) => {
  const edition = req.params.edition;
  res.send(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`dua/${edition}.json`)));
});



app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('API listening on port 3000');
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

I tried paring my code and checking the packages, but was unable to find a '?' token.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact place where you get the error, the complex error message and any stack trace, and anything else we might need to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this problem. It seems Firebase Functions and NodeJS put together do not like optionals. I had to edit a few files and simply changed the optional to a null/undefined check.

The following are the files where I found the error coming from:

- firebase-app.js
- firebase-namespace.js